# Any way to smoothly animate window.scrollTo(0, 1)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, ios

It's [well-known](http://www.joehewitt.com/blog/iphone_tips_loo.php) that iPhone web apps need to call `window.scrollTo(0, 1)` if they want to hide the native Mobile Safari toolbar. Unfortunately, this is a very jarring transition; the page slides up ~100px in one go. Is there any way to make this transition smooth?

It doesn't appear that you can use a regular JavaScript animation, because you're only going from `0` to `1`. It also doesn't appear that you could apply a CSS transition, since you're setting a DOM property (`window.scrollY`), not a CSS one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could hide all of the content on the page until the scrollTo has completed.